# Supply flares vs using the IDroid supply drop

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

The cost in BMP appears to be the same. However, the supply flares increase the deployment costs.

Why would I ever need to use the flares?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you're using the iDroid time is still running, and you remain vulnerable during that time. By contrast, flares can be thrown almost instantly.

As a result, flares are very helpful in missions where you can't just stay in one place for too long, such as boss fights.

Comment: It should be noted though, a supply flair can alert an enemy so the player still needs to use discretion if sneaking is their objective.

Answer (score 1):

I found two other forum posts that discuss this.  It seems that the main difference is that the flares are faster.  The iDroid takes longer to use since you have to go through the menu. This makes the flares more advantageous as you can use this quickly in the heat of a fight to replenish.

You can read those forum post [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/718564-metal-gear-solid-v-the-phantom-pain/72421580) and [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/718564-metal-gear-solid-v-the-phantom-pain/72457491).

Comment: I found that I can drop supply drops pretty much where even I want them to.

Comment: @Sardathrion I think you're right.  Only found one instance where someone said they can only be dropped at certain points.